# SimplePing don't work when ping to an unreachable host

Tags: ios, ping

From [Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html), I use SimplePing to check the host is reachable, but when I use an unreachable ip to test, its delegate methods

`- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

or

`- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet`

didn't invoked, and this delegate method

`- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet`

executed, any one encounter this problem, please help me. Following is my test code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) SimplePing *pinger;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pingTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *pingBtn;

- (IBAction)runWithHostName:(id)sender
{
    NSString *hostName = self.pingTextField.text;
    self.pinger = [SimplePing simplePingWithHostName:hostName];

    self.pinger.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.pinger start];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address {
    [self.pinger sendPingWithData:nil];
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet {
    NSLog(@"didSendPacket:");
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet error:(NSError *)error {
    // Eg they're not connected to any network
    NSLog(@"didFailToSendPacket: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet {
    NSLog(@"didReceivePingResponsePacket:");
}

- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceiveUnexpectedPacket:(NSData *)packet {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveUnexpectedPacket:");
}
```

when I ping to an unreachable host, the log is:

```
2014-12-23 11:45:26.933 PingHelper[1733:60695] >CFHostStartInfoResolution
2014-12-23 11:45:27.004 PingHelper[1733:60695] <CFHostStartInfoResolution
2014-12-23 11:45:27.121 PingHelper[1733:60695] >HostResolveCallback
2014-12-23 11:45:27.131 PingHelper[1733:60695] didSendPacket:
```

when I ping to a reachable host, the log is:

```
2014-12-23 11:52:37.841 PingHelper[1733:60695] >CFHostStartInfoResolution
2014-12-23 11:52:37.876 PingHelper[1733:60695] <CFHostStartInfoResolution
2014-12-23 11:52:37.882 PingHelper[1733:60695] >HostResolveCallback
2014-12-23 11:52:37.903 PingHelper[1733:60695] didSendPacket:
2014-12-23 11:52:37.903 PingHelper[1733:60695] didReceivePingResponsePacket:
```

Comment: had the same problem! anyone solve it?